# Dropdown menu not showing on IE9 if position absolute in nav li:hover ul

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu, position, nivo-slider

I am begging you for your help! I have been trying to sort out my problem for 2 days... but with no success :(

My problem is about my CSS menu. The dropdown menu is not showing on IE9 when I specify "position:absolute" in the "nav li:hover ul" section of my CSS file. But it is working in Chrome, Firefox and Safari... If I change it to "position:relative", the menu drops down but all the width of the menu at the same time... So instead of having a submenu of 160px wide, it is a 700px wide...

I have also tried to find out if it could come from NivoSlider but I didn't find any solutions...

So here is my HTML code:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html id="html">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript.js">
        </script>-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="default/default.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <title>McDonough & Co. Solicitors</title>
    </head>
    <body id="wrapper">
        <header>
            <section>
                <div id="logos">
                    <img alt="Logo" src="McDonough%20logo%20copy.png">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <img alt="Accredited by the Law Institute of Victoria"
                    src="file:///C:/Users/Paul/Desktop/Charlotte/McDonough%20Solicitors%20Website/LIV_Accreditation.png">
                <div id="address">
                    <br>68 Seymour Street,<br>Traralgon, 3844<br> Victoria
                    <br><br>&#9742; (03) 5176 1000<br>
                    <a href="mailto:law@mcdonough.com.au" target="_blank">&#9993; law@mcdonough.com.au</a><br>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>             
            </section>
            <nav id="gradients">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="file:///C:/Users/Paul/Desktop/Charlotte/McDonough%20Solicitors%20Website/Home.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="aboutus.html">About us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a>
                        <ul id="gradients2">
                            <li><a href="willsestates.html">&nbsp;Wills & Estate</a></li><br>
                            <li><a href="property.html">&nbsp;Property</a></li><br>
                            <li><a href="business.html">&nbsp;Business</a></li><br>
                            <li><a href="civillitigation.html">&nbsp;Civil Litigation</a></li><br>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="usefullinks.html">Useful Links</a>
                        <ul id="gradients3">
                            <li><a href="countycourt.html">&nbsp;County Court</a></li><br>
                            <li><a href="vicmagistratescourt.html">&nbsp;Victorian Magistrates</a></li><br>
                            <li><a href="supremecourt.html">&nbsp;Supreme Court</a></li><br>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav><br>
        </header>
        <article id="bloc_page">
            <p><section class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
                <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
                    <img src="images/image05.jpg" alt="">
                    <img src="images/image04.jpg" alt=""/>
                    <img src="images/image06.jpg" alt=""/>
                </div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(window).load(function() {
                    $('#slider').nivoSlider();
                    });
                </script>
                <div id="baseline">
                    "Your accredited Specialist in Business Law & Property Law since 1980"<br><br><br>
                </div>
                <div id="left">
                    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, erat nominati efficiendi pri cu. Mea ut simul fabulas, mea id quot admodum. No nec interesset repudiandae, in vim dolore regione, 
                    nec possit alterum forensibus ut. Qui in magna summo scripserit, cu mel agam nullam suscipiantur. Cu admodum ponderum gubergren nec, euismod consequuntur his in.
                    Id nam diam mazim persius, quem scripserit vim ad, mei cu nulla vitae. Est ex principes posidonium, libris mediocrem pro an, has sonet diceret ex. Nec cu summo constituto. 
                </div>
                <div id="right">
                    Nibh forensibus est eu, eum et hinc commodo, id justo maiestatis usu. Velit mollis assueverit pro cu.
                    Ea mea facete scripserit repudiandae. Et ubique ocurreret dissentias sea, ferri noster malorum eu vel. Aliquip admodum liberavisse sea ne, sed in nulla solet nominati. 
                    Mei an clita vivendo assueverit, omnis lorem omittam vel at. Ut bonorum scripserit vis, cum erat erroribus omittantur te, ut tacimates honestatis sea.
                </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            </section>
        </p></article>
    <br><br>
        <footer id="footer">
            <p>
            <a href="index.html">Home |</a>
            <a href="forum.html">About us |</a>
            <a href="contact.html">Services |</a>
            <a href="contact.html">Useful Links |</a>
            <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
            <br><br>
            © McDonough & Co. Solicitors 2012 - All rights reserved.<br><br>
            </p>
        </footer>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And my CSS code:

```
        /* style.css
    ---------
    By Charlotte Routier */

    /* Structure générale */
    #html
    {
    width:740px;
    margin:auto;
    background:#e6f0fa;
    }

    /* Header */
    #logo, header h1
    {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    /* Menu de navigation */
    nav
    {
    font-family: 'RawengulkBold';
    font-size: .9em;
    float: left;
    width: 700px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1200;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 15px 0 #4a4a4a;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 15px 0 #4a4a4a;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 15px 0 #4a4a4a;
    }
    nav ul
    {
    padding: 0; /* pas de marge intérieure */
    list-style-type:none;
    text-align:center;
    left: 100%; 
    z-index:1300;
    }
    nav li
    {
    float: left;
    width:100px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    list-style-type:none;
    display:inline-block;
    }
    nav ul li a
    {
    display:inline-block;  
    width:140px;
    line-height:40px; /*hauteur de l'image de fond*/
    text-decoration:none;
    }
    nav li:hover ul, nav li li:hover ul, nav li.sfhover ul, nav li li.sfhover ul /* Sous-listes lorsque la souris passe sur un élément de liste ET sous-sous-lites lorsque la souris passe sur un élément de sous-liste */
    {
    left:auto; /* Repositionnement normal */
    font-size: .8em;
    list-style-type:none;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:900;
    display:block;
    }
    nav li ul /* Sous-listes */
    {
    z-index:100;
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    text-align:left;
    width: 180px; /* Largeur des sous-listes */
    left: -999em; /* Hop, on envoie loin du champ de vision */
    text-decoration: none;
    min-height: 0;
    }
    nav a
    {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
    nav a:hover
    {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #A2C9EC;
        background: #444;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient( #555, #2C2C2C);
        background:    -moz-linear-gradient( #555, #2C2C2C);
        background:     -ms-linear-gradient( #555, #2C2C2C);
        background:      -o-linear-gradient( #555, #2C2C2C);
        background:         linear-gradient( #555, #2C2C2C);
    }
    nav a:active
    {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #a2c9ec;
        background: #444;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient( #555, #2C2C2C);
        background:    -moz-linear-gradient( #555, #2C2C2C);
        background:     -ms-linear-gradient( #555, #2C2C2C);
        background:      -o-linear-gradient( #555, #2C2C2C);
        background:         linear-gradient( #555, #2C2C2C);
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px black inset, 
                    0 1px 0 rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    }
    #gradients {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #A2C9EC 0%, #e7f2fb 100%);
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #A2C9EC 0%, #e7f2fb 100%);
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #A2C9EC 0%, #e7f2fb 100%);
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #A2C9EC 0%, #e7f2fb 100%);
    background-image:         linear-gradient(top, #A2C9EC 0%, #e7f2fb 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#A2C9EC',endColorstr='#e7f2fb', GradientType=1);
    }
    #gradients2 {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e7f2fb 0%, #A2C9EC 100%);
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e7f2fb 0%, #A2C9EC 100%);
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #e7f2fb 0%, #A2C9EC 100%);
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #e7f2fb 0%, #A2C9EC 100%);
    background-image:         linear-gradient(top, #e7f2fb 0%, #A2C9EC 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#e7f2fb',endColorstr='#A2C9EC', GradientType=0);
    }
    #gradients3 {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e7f2fb 0%, #A2C9EC 100%);
    background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e7f2fb 0%, #A2C9EC 100%);
    background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #e7f2fb 0%, #A2C9EC 100%);
    background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #e7f2fb 0%, #A2C9EC 100%);
    background-image:         linear-gradient(top, #e7f2fb 0%, #A2C9EC 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#e7f2fb',endColorstr='#A2C9EC', GradientType=0);
    }

    /* Slideshow */
    .nivoSlider {
    background:url(/nivo-slider/themes/bar/loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    width: 700px !important;
    height: 230px !important;
    z-index:1;
    float:center;
    position:absolute;
    display:inline-block; 
    }
    .theme-default .nivoSlider img {
    width: 700px !important;
    height: 230px !important;
    z-index:1;
    }

    /* Corps du texte */
    body
    {
    background-color: #ffffff; /* Le fond de la page sera blanc */
    color: #000; /* Le texte de la page sera noir */
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 15px 0 #4a4a4a;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 15px 0 #4a4a4a;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 15px 0 #4a4a4a;
    }
    #wrapper 
    {
    width:700px;
    margin:0 auto;
    }
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'Rawengulk';
    src: url('RawengulkDemibold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('RawengulkDemibold-webfont.otf') format('truetype'),
         url('RawengulkDemibold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('RawengulkDemibold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('RawengulkDemibold-webfont.svg#QuadrantaBold') format('svg');
    }
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'RawengulkBold';
    src: url('RawengulkBold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('RawengulkBold-webfont.otf') format('truetype'),
         url('RawengulkBold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('RawengulkBold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('RawengulkBold-webfont.svg#QuadrantaBold') format('svg');
    }
    #address
    {
    font-family: 'RawengulkBold';
    color: #000;
    font-size: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
    margin-left:20px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height: 18px;
    }
    #baseline
    {
    font-family: 'RawengulkBold';
    color: #000;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-align: center;
    }
    #left
    {
    font-family: 'Calibri';
    color: #323232;
    font-size: .8em;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 320px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:2px;
    }
    #right
    {
    font-family: 'Calibri';
    color: #323232;
    font-size: .8em;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 320px;
    float:right;
    margin-right:2px;
    }
    img
    {
    vertical-align:middle;
    }
    p
    {
    color: #000;
    font-size: .7em; 
    font-family: 'Rawengulk';
    width:100%; /* On a indiqué une largeur (obligatoire) */
    float: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
    a /* Liens par défaut (non survolés) */
    {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    }
    a:hover /* Apparence au survol des liens */
    {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #000;
    }
    a:active 
    {
    background-color: none;
    }
    #footer
    {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    float: center;
    text-align: center;
    }
```

Do not hesitate to ask if you require more details.

Hopefully you can help me! Many thanks in advance.
Charlotte

PS : here are two images (one showing the dropdown menu working with Chrome and the other one with IE, not working)

- http://dl.dropbox.com/u/45202596/IE9.jpg
- http://dl.dropbox.com/u/45202596/Chrome.jpg

Comment: Can you provide a link to your site?

Comment: "nav li ul" is being floated left and positioned absolute. I don't think you can really do both.

Comment: Hi Billy, thanks for getting back to me! I removed "float:left" from "nav li ul" but it doesn't change anything unfortunately. If I remove "position:absolute" the dropdown menu stays constantly.
I can't really give you a link to my website as it's not live yet... sorry!

Comment: Billy, I added two screen shots so you have a better idea of what I am saying... Thanks!

Comment: Analyzing an issue like that without a live example and a change to reproduce the bug will take a lot of time. Not many people around here will be willing to take a look at your code and help you. Spend few minutes, create some kind of a free hosting account and upload your website there. It will take you 10 minutes and decrease the time of analyzing your code by 10 times.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the parent of the absolute positioned element(s) so ensure that is positioned relative? An absolutely positioned element will be positioned relative to its parent container. Some browsers will assume the parent is positioned relative if no other declaration is specified. Other browsers will take your code literally and not be so kind. Can you also use Firebug in Firefox (or similar tool) to ensure the element is being 'displayed' somewhere on the page and is just suffering from a position problem? If it isn't, it could be the rendering of the hover target which isn't then requesting the menu to display. Padding, display:block; and width/height declarations in IE are the common causes of that sort of problem.